# NoSQL vs SQL Dynamic Form

Tags: sql, asp.net, forms, nosql

I'm implementing dynamic forms. As a user I want to be able to dynamically create a form. Give it a name, let's say 'Employee Form' and assign fields to the form like 'Name: String' , Birth of Date: Date'.

Later I want to be able to use these form definitions to store values of these forms and use it in multiple places.

Basically I just want to be able to store any configuration object I want in the database and then using some webservice to retrieve it and show it in the webpage.

I've started to design MySQL database for that but I think using NoSQL database for such task might be a better solution. Would you suggest using NoSql (Mongo) for such task rather than SQL?

In SQL I would have tables like Form ('Employee Form') , FormFieldsNames ('Name', 'DateOfBirth'), FieldType('String', 'Date', 'Integer') and then FormFieldValues('Name: John', 'DateOfBirth: 1985/01/01')

I'm using asp.net on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to what you have said, I actually think that MongoDB is the easiest solution, because it is schemaless and allows you to represent array of things (in this case, fields) in a convenient way. In that case, you would need a *form* collection, containing the description of your forms (eg.

```
{ 
  "name":"Employee form",
  "associatedCollection":"somethingUniqueAndMaybeRandom",
  "fields": [
              { "Name":"String"}, 
              { "Date of birth":"Date"}
             ] 
}
```

), and then a collection for each form, containing the actual data. Or something similar.

With SQL databases the solution is not so straightforward, as you are experimenting, but not much harder I think. So you can choose both, IMO; I would choose MongoDB, but there is not much difference up to me.